# Kernel and Image of a group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

let $G$ be   a multiplicative group of non-zero complex analysis.consider the group homomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow G$ defined by $\phi(z)=z^4$.

1.Identify kernel of $\phi=H$.

2.Identify $G/H$

My try:

let $z\in \ker \phi$  then $\phi(z)=1\implies z^4=1$
let $z=re^{i\theta}\implies r^4\cos 4\theta =1;r^4\sin 4\theta =0$

then $r=1$ and $\tan 4\theta=0\implies 4\theta=0\implies \theta=\frac{n\pi}{2}$

Is it correct?

I cant proceed in the 2nd problem.

Any hints in this regard.

Comment: Just to be clear: $G$ is *the* multiplicative group of non-zero complex *numbers*, right?

Comment: yes you are  @lhf

Answer (score 2):

You are right about the first point, just finish off by noting the the kernel has four elements, and try and list them (this will turn out to be easy).

As to the second point, remember the so-called fundamental theorem of algebra: in particular, for each complex number $a$, there is $z$ such that $z^{4} = a$.

Comment: my answer to 1 is $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$ and to the second it is $G$.is it right?

Comment: @learnmore, yes. To be clear, the *image* of $\phi$ is the whole $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. If  $z \in \ker \phi$ then $\phi (z) = 1$. Think of the fourth root of unit.
2. Use the [Isomorphism Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem).

If $\xi$ is a n-th root of unit and $z ^n = a$ then $a\xi$ is a root of $z^n - a = 0$.